# How to modify the Firefox homepage in LiveCD for every new user?

Tags: firefox, live-cd

I have made a custom Ubuntu LiveCD with [UCK](http://uck.sourceforge.net/). How do I modify Firefox's homepage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've newer tried to use uck,
but I would try the following:

The skeleton-directory for the ubuntu user is

```
/etc/skel
```

so create the folder:

```
/etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/
```

in this folder create a file "profiles.ini" with content:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=a.default
```

Now add a folder

```
/etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/a.default/
```

In this folder create a file named user.js with content:

```
//
// user.js: Personal prefs which mozilla shouldn't overwrite.
//

user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk");
```

greez Waschtl

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/firefox/syspref.js` and add:

```
pref("browser.startup.homepage", "http://example.com/");
```

This will probably only affect profiles which have not modified the homepage on their own though.